# Does Pycharm with Anaconda run script when Windows logs out/hibernates?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm currently waiting for my script to finish working. It's been 26 hours, while it was supposed to run around 20. I left Windows logged out for the night and now I'm thinking if it did work while logged out.
Second thing I'm an idiot and unplugged my laptop for a 'while', while needing a socket, and it hibernated before I managed to react. After plugging in Pycharm seems to be running the code as if nothing happened (I know cause the first couple of seconds after starting the script it spits out some data and the data was already there after wakingup from hibernation).

I can't afford to waste days testing it and I found no info online. Should I hope it finishes soon and can I leave it logged out for another night? The actual uptime while logged in was less than 6 hours.

Comment: Your question is unclear and not a question about Python. I suggest adding some useful logging to your script, writing it so it can deal with interruptions and not turning your computer off if it's doing something important.

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of program is this?

Comment: @AMC: It's generating all the possible subsets of n vertices from among k of them in a graph, then calculating certain quality of the n and looking for the best subset. This one is 6 out of 64. It's very bad, but it's an ultimate test to see if the actual script I'm working on produces comparable results.